# Auto Refreshing Highcharts with PHP/JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, highcharts

Im attempting to get a highcharts chart to refresh every minute with new data. So far I have the chart being created using a php outputting on a header as javascript.

I have this at the top of the page:

```
<?php
    //set the output header as JS
    Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
    //output start of javascript chart
?>
   var chart;
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
```

Then some PHP to get the data from the database, and output in the highcharts format.

I Now have this on my index page calling the graph, it displays, then does destroy the graph,  and redisplays the graph but it doesn't seem to re-run the php code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false,
    });
    $.get("api_dashchart.php?uID=<?php echo $userInfo_ID; ?>");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
        if(chart) chart.destroy();
        $.get("api_dashchart.php?uID=<?php echo $userInfo_ID; ?>");
    }, 45000);
});
```

Continued help much appreciated.

Comment: The data will not update, because I assume it is being built by your php code. You will need to use JavaScript to do an AJAX call to pull in your charts new data from an external php script. This will mean separating your php into a separate file, which can then be called, and the result loaded into the page using javascript. Take a look at the jquerys ajax function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing server and client code here,
You PHP code will **only be executed once on the server, while the page is fetched.**

```
window.setInterval(function(
    displaygraph();
}, 60000);
```

Cannot update data, it will only re-execute displaygraph(), but the data inside this method is not updated from server, but the data that was fetched during page load will be used, you will need to use AJAX, and make an ajax request to get updated data and then use it to redraw the chart with newly fetched data. Try debugging you javascript using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).
As for the first load issue, you can easily do it with an if statement inside display graph.

```
if(chart) chart.destroy();
```

To sum it up,

charting.js

```
var chart;
function displaygraph() {
 $.getJSON("getjson.php", function(json) {
  if(chart) chart.destroy();
  //get data from json, and use in chart
  chart = new Highcharts.Chart({....});
});
setInterval(displaygraph, 60000);
```

getjson.php

```
<?php
  $data = ...
  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

More on $.getJSON @ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ , $.ajax @ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ json-encoding in php @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Thanks. Thats definately starting to point me in the right direction, i'm a beginner when it comes to Javascript.
Would the $.getJSON work if I kept it all in one file still and just called the whole file? Atm the php and echo's out the necessary JS in loops, so would be difficult to separate this.
Basically, what i think i need is a Jquery function that can call the PHP file every few minutes and at the same time, destory the previous graph, or even just only reload the stuff thats changed, think thats chart.reload().

Comment: Would this be heading in the right direction?
'<script>
    $(function() { 
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
    $.get("api_dashchart.php?uID=<?php echo $userInfo_ID; ?>");
   }, 1000);
  });
    });
</script>'

Comment: Since the only part in your chart that changes is the data, so ideally you should only ask ajax to return only the new data for you. But you can also ask for the entire chartingOptions from server @ every poll is you wish to
<?php // Everything existing stays in php
  $chartingOptions =...
  echo json_encode($chartingOptions);
?>
// This is all you will need in js
var chart;
$(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$.getJSON("getjson.php", function(chartingOptions) {
  if(chart) chart.destroy();
  //get data from json, and use in chart
  chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartingOptions);
}
},1000);
}